# How do I change the "primary group" for an existing user?

Tags: macos, user-account, unix, group

My current primary group (the `gid` I see listed by `id`) is me, rather than `staff`. I'd like to change it to `staff`, without changing anything else about my user account. How do I change the "primary group" (PrimaryGroupID) for my account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to change your group is through the MacOS System Preferences panel. Open it, and then open the **Users & Groups** panel. Unlock the lock icon in the bottom-left so that you can enter your password and make changes.

Once the panel is unlocked, you can right-click (or option-click) on the user you want to change and select **Advanced Options** from the popup-menu. The advanced options panel will let you specify your default group.

To change the primary group from the **command line**, first get the ID number of the group and then set the primary group id to that value:

Get a list of groups. You may want to pipe this through less.

```
# dscacheutil -q group
```

Change user "scott"'s primary id to 20:

```
# dscl . -create /Users/scott PrimaryGroupID 20
```

[This solution is from Richard York's blog post on dscl](http://www.deadmarshes.com/Blog/20111105010130.html)
*Original link dead Oct 15* - now [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20140718215310/http://www.deadmarshes.com/Blog/20111105010130.html)

Comment: Where it says just "Group"? Is there a way to do it from the command line?

Comment: Thanks! My old group was `rax`, which is my user name (both 501). Is there any reason to preserve that by adding myself back as a member of the `rax` group (though not as primary). Without doing so will I still have access to all files with `rax:rax` permissions?

Comment: Glad to help. I'd add yourself to that group just in case - no harm in doing so. If you don't add yourself to the group, then you'd run the risk of not being able to access a file.

Comment: looks like with this steps there's additional field `egid` gets added and which still points to staff. is that expected? or is there a way to change that as well