# How to remove a user from staff group in macOS?

Tags: macos

How on earth do I remove one of my local user accounts from the default "staff" group in macOS? I've tried many of the obscure commands in the command-line to no avail, i.e dscl, dseditgroup.

This is what I tried:

```
$ dsmemberutil checkmembership -U someuser -G staff
user is a member of the group
```

Tried removing:

```
$ sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d someuser -t user staff
```

Checking membership:

```
$ dsmemberutil checkmembership -U someuser -G staff
user is a member of the group
```

How come?

I want to remove a particular local account from the staff group so that it doesn't have access to the contents of home directories of other local accounts, amongst other things.

Any commands and/or GUIs that you can recommend for this?

Comment: Pay attention on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574494/2174275

Comment: The command you gave worked for me to remove a user from the `admin` and `wheel` groups that I had previously manually added (tested on OS X 10.12).

Answer (score 2):

I was also having trouble with this, all the other resources/answers I had found didn't work for me. I finally figured it out (have only tested on my machine on Catalina). This is kind of a kitchen sink approach so some of these steps might be unnecessary, but this is what I did and it worked. I'm not an apple engineer so YMMV and do at your own risk.

Say we want to remove staff group for a user with the name "someuser"

1. Setup a shell script like this: https://superuser.com/a/395738 (see also notes at end of this answer) it'll make debugging easier. Assuming you've saved it in a file members.sh with executable permission, You can double check that it is working by doing:

```
./members.sh  staff
```

and seeing if someuser appears in the list.

2. From the system preferences UI create a new group, you can do this by under "Users & Groups" hitting the plus sign and selecting group in the drop-down box. It doesn't matter what you call it, we'll say "new_group"
3. Select that group in the UI and check the box next to "someuser"
4. Right click on "new_group" from the UI and select advanced options, copy the Group ID # (not UUID), it should be a regular number. Say the number is 1234.
5. Now we are going to change someusers's primary group to new_group instead of staff (see also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81553/409162). Do the following:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser PrimaryGroupID 1234
```

(where 1234 is the number you copied in step 4)

6. Right click on someuser from the UI, select "Advanced Options" and in the "Group" textbox, change "staff" to "new_group". If you close and re-open this "Advanced Options" window it should stay set to new_group.
7. Finally remove the user from staff. Run the following (note: I got this from the "EXAMPLES" section of `man dseditgroup` you may want to double check there to confirm)

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -u someuser -p -d someuser -t user staff
```

You may have to enter your password because it is a sudo command, but when it says "Please enter user password" this refers to someusers's password.

8. Run `./members.sh staff` to check that someuser was successfully removed. If someuser is still in the list:

   - Restart your computer
   - Re-run the command in step #7
   - Check again

I've tried this a couple times, sometimes restarting was necessary, other times it wasn't. Sometimes re-running the command was necessary, other times it wasn't

---

## Notes

The shell script from step 1, copied and pasted from https://superuser.com/a/395738:

```
#!/bin/bash

# members -- list all members of a group
#
# SYNOPSIS
#   members groupname
#
# http://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x
#  by Arne
# Expected to work on Mac OS 10.5 and newer, tested on 10.6 and 10.7.
# It could be rewritten to work on 10.4 by using "dseditgroup -o checkmember"
# instead of "dsmemberutil checkmembership".
# By using dseditgroup, the script could also be extended to handle
# other Directory Service nodes than the default local node.
#

the_group="$1"
# Input check and usage
  if [[ $# != 1 || $1 == -* || $1 =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} groupname" >&2
    echo "Lists all members of the group." >&2
    exit 64
  elif (dsmemberutil checkmembership -U root -G "$the_group" 2>&1 \
    | grep "group .* cannot be found") >&2; then
    exit 1
  fi

# Check every user
exec dscl . -list /Users \
  | while read each_username
  do
    printf "$each_username "
    dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "$each_username" -G "$the_group"
  done \
    | grep "is a member" | cut -d " " -f 1

# eof
```

Comment: I don't see a script in the superuser answer you linked to

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm not sure why since I am still able to see it, but I've copied and pasted to this answer as well in case it helps.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Rather than the script, you can just do 'id <user>' to see what groups the user is in. The script will be a helpful starting point for anyone wanting to apply it to other DS nodes, though.